# is there no way to catch "Received an unexpected URL from the web process:"

Tags: html, ios, swift, href, wkwebview

I'm attempting to rewrite an objective-c app using a UIWebViewsin Swift using a WKWebView.
The application displays a lot of local content.
While I can display the initial webpage in WKWebView with no problem.  When I click on a link that points to more local content I get the following error:

Received an unexpected URL from the web process: "..."

The content uses a nonstandard href to identify the local content.  Using the UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest api I was able to intercept this clicked linked and rewrite the href in a way that I could load the appropriate local content.

So far I haven't been able to identify anything in WKWebView that would allow me to accomplish the same thing.
I'm consuming this content, not creating it so I don't have the option of changing the format of the href.

I've tried:

decidePolicyFor navigationResponse
decidePolicyFor navigationAction
didFail navigation
didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation
didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation

I tried adding a custom URLSchemeHandler...
nothing allowed me to intercept the link.

Instead in the console I get errors:

Received an unexpected URL from the web process:
Received an invalid message "WebPageProxy.DecidePolicyForNavigationAction" from the web process.
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service

It DO get decideActionPolicyFor:

Am I missing something? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Morgan Jones

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm running into the same problem. iOS doesn't seem to be able to access my index.html file located in the directory above.

Comment: hi @morgman did you got solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is way,use this function

```
func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(WKWebView){}
```

for catching the error and you can either navigate back or reload the webview.

Comment: Nice I will give this a try

Comment: yeah sure I was also facing that error in my project it worked.

Answer (score 0):

WKURLSchemeHandler is the way to go for WKWebView.

We have found however that code like:

"script type="text/javascript" src="xxx-local:.js"

does not recognise our custom scheme when page is accessed via https.

Same for style sheets.
Still works for images though.

What does your link look like?

P.S. You can't intercept a known scheme (e.g. http)

Comment: Unfortunately I tried WKURLSchemeHandler already... even though it causes WKWebView an error, it interprets the HREF as "file://", a known scheme, that I can't override >.<